# Checking the values of one column in a column in another dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have two Pyspark dataframes(DF1 and DF2). I want to check whether the cities in DF1 is available in the cities column in DF2 and if yes, then return the country name from DF2 and create a new dataframe DF3 with Sl.No, City and Country.

DF1
Sl.No   City
1       a
2       b
2       c
4       d
5       e

DF2
Country Cities
W       a
V       b,c 
X       d,e

DF3
Sl.No   City    Country
1       a       W
2       b       V
3       c       V
4       d       X
5       e       X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using explode

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

l1 = [(1, 'a', ), (2, 'b', ), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l1, ['sino','city'])
#df1.show()

l1 = [('W', ['a'] ), ('V', ['b','c'] ), ('X', ['d', 'e'])]
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l1, ['ctry','cities'])
#df2.show()

df2 = df2.withColumn('cityName', F.explode('cities'))

df3 = df1.join(df2, df1.city == df2.cityName).drop('cities', 'cityName')

df3.show()

+----+----+----+
|sino|city|ctry|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   a|   W|
|   3|   c|   V|
|   5|   e|   X|
|   2|   b|   V|
|   4|   d|   X|
+----+----+----+
```